# Least-squares polynomial fitting

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to fit this polynomial with leastsq? The aim is to get a graph optimized from the experimental and analytical values:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import pylab as py
import numpy as np
```

## x_data is temperature, y_data is analytical and y1_data is experimental

```
x_data=[329.74403, 329.21733, 328.73927, 328.25111, 327.75969, 327.26852, 
326.7746,326.28142, 325.78471,325.28635,324.78976]
y_data=[]
y1_data=[1.55e-06, 1.82e-06, 1.93e-06, 1.17e-06, 1.93e-06, 1.79e-06, 1.31e- 
06, 1.75e-06,1.68e-06,1.39e-06, 1.69e-06]

Tavg = sum(x_data)/len(x_data)
B=0.33
m0 = 1.0
st = 0.1 * Tavg

def p(Tc):
    return 1.0/(np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)*st)*np.exp(-((Tc- 
    Tavg)**2.0)/(2.0*st**2.0))


def F(Tc, Ti):
    if (Tc-Ti) <0:
       return 0
    else:
       return ((Tc-Ti)/Tc)**B*p(Tc)
```

## this function gives out the analytical values

```
def M(t):
    for Ti in x_data:
       k = quad(F, 0.0, 2000.0, args=(Ti,))[0]
       y_data.append(k*m0)

#graph of temperature vs analytical is done here
def plt():
    py.xlabel('Temperature')
    py.ylabel('Magnetisation')
    py.plot(x_data,y_data)
    py.savefig('graf.png')
```

I need to find a graph optimized using leastsq which minimizes the error between the analytical and experimental value. I have looked online for leastsq examples but I had a hard time understanding and applying it to my code. Any help and insight is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to do the fitting and [`numpy.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval) to get the data to plot.

```
coefficients = numpy.polyfit(x_data, y_data, degree)

fitted_data = numpy.polyval(coefficients, x_data)
```

### Example usage

Generate and plot some random data that looks like stock price data:

```
from pylab import *

data = 10 + np.cumsum(np.random.normal(0.1, 0.1, size=100))
plot(data); grid(True); show()
```

You get something like this:

[image]

Then, do the fitting (get the coefficients of a polynomial that approximates your data) and the data to plot (evaluate the polynomial given by the coefficients you got):

```
X = np.arange(0, data.size)

coeff = np.polyfit(X, data, 5)
Y_fitted = np.polyval(coeff, X)

plot(Y_fitted); grid(True); show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

But to see the power of `np.polyfit`, we need one more graph: original data (orange) vs the polynomial (blue):

[image]

As you can see, on this concrete interval the polynomial approximates your data pretty well, and the higher the degree of the polynomial, the better the approximation.

Comment: Does the degree in the coefficient function have any value? and what is the use for fitted data? I would honestly prefer if you had used the leastsq function but still thanks for your input in curve_fit. Curve_fit however doesn't seem to work for me as the graph should be heading down in theory but in your pic, it is going up.

Comment: @VillaSega, I didn't say anything about `curve_fit`, what are you talking about? I used random data for the graph, so it might be going up or down for you, and this is perfectly fine. The degree has a lot of meaning: the higher the degree, the better the approximation. You said you wanted a graph of the approximation, so to do that you should compute the value of the polynomial for all points in `X`, which is what `np.polyval` does. Also, this method already uses Least Squares automatically.